# eChartsjs on React - trying to disabling the hover effect on the pointer

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I'm using echarts-for-react to create a gauge. I'm trying to disable the hover effect on the pointer.
The current behaviour is that I have a circle with a small pointer, and when hovering, the pointer covers the text. I've tried setting emphasis: null but it didn't change anything.

Here's the pictures demonstrating this issue:

[Normal Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxkgH.png)

[When hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzTGB.png)

Here's my code:

```
const series = {
      type: 'gauge',
      radius: '100%',
      startAngle: '-20',
      endAngle: '200',
      clockWise: false,
      data: [ltv],
      max: 150,
      axisLine: {
        show: true,
        lineStyle: {
          width: '12',
          color: [[0.2, '#e2da34'], [0.4, '#c2e234'], [0.6, '#7dea52'], [0.8, '#c2e234'], [1, '#e2da34']],
          shadowColor: '#f5f5f5',
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowOffsetX: 5,
          shadowOffsetY: 5
        }
      },
      splitLine: {
        show: false
      },
      axisTick: {
        show: false
      },
      axisLabel: {
        show: false
      },
      pointer: {
        length: '100%',
        width: '4'
      },
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#d1d1d1',
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderColor: '#d1d1d1'
      },
      detail: {
        show: true,
        formatter: e => [`{val|${e.toFixed(1)}%}`, '{text|Good!}'].join('\n'),
        rich: {
          val: {
            color: '#2f353a',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontFamily: 'SegoePro-Bold',
            fontSize: '24'
          },
          text: {
            color: '#9c9c9c',
            fontFamily: 'SegoePro-Regular',
            fontSize: '12'
          }
        },
        offsetCenter: [0, 0],
        padding: [40, 10, 0, 10],
        width: 85,
        height: 65,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 50,
        borderShadow: '#000000'
      }
    };

    const config = {
      title: {
        show: false
      },
      legend: {
        show: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        show: false
      },
      series
    };
```